# AngularJS Image Preview before Upload showing previous image selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
    myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
    var modelSetter = model.assign;
    element.bind('change', function(e) {
      $scope.$apply(function(e) {
        modelSetter($scope, element[0].files[0]);
      });
      $scope.setimage();
    });
  }
```

The above code is my directive.

In the function $scope.setimage()

```
     $scope.setimage = function() {
  var file = $scope.myFile;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $scope.ImageSrc = e.target.result;
  }
}
```

Whenever i choose the file,

```
  <img width= 250 height=350 ng-src="{{ImageSrc}}"/>
  <input type=`enter code here`"file" file-model="myFile"/>
```

Immediately the preview is not appearing. When i choose the second time, the preview for the previously selected image file is appearing. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: you need to $apply() your change. Can probably find some use in these methods: http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2014/6/2/How-do-I-run-code-when-a-variable-changes-with-AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `element.bind('change', ...`, you can use `$scope.$watch` on myFile, like so:

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.myFile', function(e) {
  $scope.$apply(function(e) {
    modelSetter($scope, element[0].files[0]);
  });
  $scope.setimage();
});
```

Note that `$scope.myFile` needs to be defined for this to occur, so if it's not defined in your directive you'll need to add this to your controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

I added $scope.$apply for the imagesrc assignment and the image updated immediately.

```
   $scope.setimage = function() {
   var file = $scope.myFile;
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function(e) {
     $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.ImageSrc = e.target.result;
    });  }
   }
```